# Inflating ConstraintLayout in another ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I want to put a ConstraintLayout programmaticly in another ConstraintLayout. But it does not show up, if I inflate it the way I did before with a RelativeLayout.

Here's the code inner file inner_area.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/innerArea"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grade_one"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/onegreen"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/h1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/v1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="20dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="30dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteY="0dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grade_three"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/threelila"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/h2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/v1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/h1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="20dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="30dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteY="20dp" />
    .....
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Outer LayoutFile parent.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/parentView"
android:background="@color/primary">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Javacode:

```
    ViewGroup parentView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.parentView);
    final ConstraintLayout innerArea = (ConstraintLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_area, container, false);
    parentView.addView(innerArea);
```

But when I change in the inner.xml the layout_width or layout_height of the innerArea to wrap_content or match_parent, nothing happens. But when I change to 2000dp the inner layout shows up.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: You are inflating with `container` as the parent in `inflate()` but you are adding the inflated layout to `parentView`. This doesn't seem right. It would be helpful to know what `rootView` and `container` are. This looks like part of a fragment's `onCreateView()`, so a look at the fragment transaction could be helpful, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Cheticamp for pointing me in the right direction. I was inflating the ConstraintLayout with the root layout and not with the Constraint Layout it is supposed to be in. So the correct Javacode is:

```
    parentView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.parentView);
    ViewGroup parentView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.parentView);
    final ConstraintLayout innerArea = (ConstraintLayout) 
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.inner_area, parentView, false);
    parentView.addView(innerArea);
```

Answer (score 2):

I seem to be very late to the party but I tried lots of things to solve this problem but nothing worked.

I ended up just putting the inner constraint layout inside another layout (a relative layout in my case) which solved the problem for me.